# how to sort array of dictionary by case insensitive in swift

Tags: swift2

I have the following code which sort the array of dictionary alphabetically in ascending order. But I got the sorted small letter key value after capital letters. ex. if key has values like "Jast", "rat", "Put" , "put", "Avi", "Que" . I m getting the output like   "Avi","Jast","Put", "Que", "put", "rat" which is not sorted .  I used following code

```
let sortedArray = ( 
   episode_ParticipantList as NSArray
).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(
 [NSSortDescriptor(key: "FirstName", ascending: true)])
 as!
 [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
let sortedArray = episode_ParticipantList.sort{
    $0["FirstName"]?.lowercaseString < $1["FirstName"]?.lowercaseString
}
```

This might be faster, but you'll need to test:

```
import Foundation

let sortedArray = episode_ParticipantList.sort{
    $0["FirstName"]!.caseInsensitiveCompare($1["FirstName"]!) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**IN SWIFT 4**

```
responseData = responseData.sorted { ($0["firstname"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1["firstname"] as! String) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```